# CSS Table within table

Tags: css

So, after hours of struggle, I decided to ask for help.

To better explain, I added an image that has three figures.
As you can see in the Figure 2 and 3, that is the format that I am trying to achieve. I added Figure 1 to show my logic behind it.

[image]

Here is CSS that I tried and failed.

```
.red{width:100%;display:table;}
.redrow {display:table-row; width:100%;}
.firstgreencell{width:70%; display:table-cell;}
.yellowtable{width:100%; display:table;}
.yellowrow{width:100%; display:table-row;}
.yellowfirst{width:30%; display:table-cell;}
.yellowsecond{width:70%; display:table-cell;}
.ysrow{display:table-row;}
.ysrowtop{display:table-column; height:50%;}
.ysrowbottom{display:table-column; height:50%;)
.secondgreencell{width:30%; display:table-cell;}
```

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="red"> table(1st) (outer most table)
     <div class="redrow">   table-row (which includes two green cells)   
          <div class="firstgreencell"> table-cell (first green cell on the left)
            <div class="yellowtable">  table(2nd) (inner yellow table)
               <div class="yellowrow"> table-row (includes inner yellow cells)
                  <div class="yellowfirst"> Content X: table-cell  (left yellow cell that has "Content X")</div>                                
                  <div class="yellowsecond"> table-cell  (right yellow cell)
                      <div class="ysrow"> table-row (includes two right cells)
                         <div class="ysrowtop">  Content Y-Top: table-column (includes "Content Y-top) </div>   
                         <div class="ysrowbottom"> Content Y-bottom: table-column(includes "Content Y-bottom)</div> 
                      </div>
                  </div>    
              </div>    
           </div>   
        </div>                      
       <div class="secondgreencell">Content-Z: far right green cell</div>   
     </div>
  </div>
```

Any suggestions to how I can achieve this table format?

Thanks!

Comment: Please create SO Snippet with HTML and css

Comment: Also: What is your actual question?

Comment: I edited the question. I want to know how I can achieve Figure 2 looking using display:table.

Comment: Why not use regular tables for this?

Comment: Please provide the html code as well.

Comment: I added the html code and edited the image.